# How to communicate b/w chrome native messaging app( console ) and winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome-extension, ipc, chrome-native-messaging

I have created a chrome extension with native app messaging. The native app is written in (Winforms) c#. It starts as soon as we check on to the extension. I need to show the app only when the user clicks on .exe file. So my idea is to create a console application as an Native messaging application. When the user click on extension, the console app will run in background. When the user clicks on .exe 
(winforms), the Winform app will launch and communicate with the console app.

Is it the best approach i can go with? And how can i establish the communication b/w console app and winforms?

Comment: You already have a question on this topic, and I described the approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531010/need-to-open-chrome-native-app-on-click-of-it-not-at-the-time-of-enable-the-exe/25545280#25545280

Comment: Though this question seems more about how to establish communication between a separate UI-less native host and a GUI app, right?

Comment: @Xan: Yes, xan actually the problem is on how to establish a connection b/w already running console app from winforms

Comment: @Xan : With the solution you suggested, there will be no communication b/w the exe opened up by user and opened up by chrome. am i right?

Comment: Wrong. In my solution, every opened instance of the app looks for and messages other instances, if present. See the link in my answer for more ideas on how to implement that.

Comment: @Xan: Ooh. Really sorry, I didn't understood the answer at that time.So how can I Message that instance to show UI ? PipLine method?

Comment: @xan : Ok, Got that link. Thanks Xan.

Comment: @Xan: I tried the solution suggested by you, but when i show the Ui , two instance of the .exe start. one is in backgroung and other is with UI. Any idea on this? I have added a question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296142/how-to-make-the-winform-background-process-to-show-the-ui